# Magento 2 -All thumbnails not display

Tags: magento2, static-content, thumbnail

I installed `Magento` in `XAMPP`, and the installation is fully complete. However, when I go to `Fontend` and `Backend`, the loading is very long, also all the thumbnails crash. I tried install again, but the same problem is still here.

I find out a error on console, it seems no any file in the directory:
[image]

Here is my backend, all the thumbnail crash and the loading is unstopptable.
[image]

How can I solve the infinitely-loading and the thumbnail problem?

Comment: Did you run static deploy command?

Comment: No... I am trying now..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

run command `./bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

or

`php -f magento setup:static-content:deploy`

from console

Answer (score 0):

When you installed magento 2 the admin links wont work. In order to make the links to work. Goto magento root folder app/etc/di.xml then comment this line

```
<item name="view_preprocessed" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink</item>
```

and paste this code

```
<item name="default" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy</item>
```

save and check links will work. Also do reindex using

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

To display thumbnails do static content deployment using

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```